# Method invocation failed because [Sitecore.Data.Items.Item] does not contain a method named 'op_Addition'

Tags: powershell, sitecore

I have a powershell script in which I need to create a report of items that match a condition, but I need to store those items within a list (guiltyItems), outside of my functions context, and the error from the title is returned.

> Method invocation failed because [Sitecore.Data.Items.Item] does not
>   contain a method named 'op_Addition'

It fails here: `$global:guiltyItems += $_;`

Is there a way in Sitecore powershell to create a list of Sitecore items and populate it?

If it has any relevance, the call to the `Process-Richtext` function is made from a foreach loop, which is within another foreach loop:

```
$global:guiltyItems = $null;

function Process-RichText
{
    param(  [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)] [Sitecore.Data.Fields.Field]$field,
            [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)] [string]$pattern,
            [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)] [Sitecore.Data.Items.Item]$_)

    $allMatches = [System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex]::Matches($field.Value,$pattern);
    foreach ($match in $allMatches)
    {
        $currentItem = Get-Item master -Id ([Sitecore.Data.ID]::Parse($match.Groups["sitecoreid"].Value)).Guid;

        if ($currentItem.Template.Id -eq $quiltyTemplate)
        {
            $global:guiltyItems += $_;
        }
    }
}

[...]

ForEach ($item in $allItems) {
    foreach ($field in $item.Fields)
    {
        if ($field.Id -eq $RichTextContentID -and ($field.Value -match $internalLinkPattern))
        {
           Process-RichText $field $internalLinkPattern $item;
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Try explicit array declaration: `$global:guiltyItems = @()` instead of assigning it as `$null`.

Comment: Solved my issue. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is caused by dynamic typing. The script starts by setting `guiltyItems` to null, so it has no type. Nothing strange so far. Typing problem rises in the foreach loop.

```
$global:guiltyItems = $null;
...
foreach ($match in $allMatches) {
    ...
    if ($currentItem.Template.Id -eq $quiltyTemplate) {
        $global:guiltyItems += $_; # Boom!
```

So what happens here is that null variable has no type. In the foreach loop, processed variables do have types, as they aren't nulls. The first iteration will set `guiltyItems` to whatever type the iterated object is. Like the error message claims, adding two `Sitecore.Data.Items.Item` makes no sense.

When `guiltyItems` is declared as an array, addition makes sense. It's not adding two Sitecore items together but adding new elements to the collection.

Should your collection contain just a single element, the script would be likely to work without a hick. That's because the addition is called only once.

As per the comment, to resolve the issue, declare `$global:guiltyItems` explicitly as an array like so,

```
$global:guiltyItems = @()
```